# Can I connect USB voltage in parallel or in series to get more either more voltage or more current?

Tags: power, current, usb

USB 2.0 provides up to 0.5 amperes of current.

Can I connect several USB cables/ports in parallel from SINGLE computer to have more than 0.5 A?

Or this has no sense since single computer shares power between different USB ports anyway?

The second question is can I connect USBs in series to have `10V`, `15V` and so on?

Comment: Have you searched google for that yet? What did you find?

Comment: Isn't this the whole point of Y-cables?

Comment: @bwDraco so are Y-cables reasonable?

Comment: @Dims - If you google "Can I connect USB voltage parallel to get more power?", you will end up right back on stackexchage. Your question has been asked here, and in many other corners of the internet. Do some research first.

Comment: @Bort then just mark duplicate qstn, what's the problem? The case is common.

Comment: I believe there is a continuous public confusion about USB capabilities, 100mA versus 500mA or 900mA, and between "what one can get" and "why my phone does not take that much". This confusion is revolving and revolving. Is there some mechanism like "wiki" on this site, so the topic can be clarified once for all?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is two-fold, 
(A1) Y-cables do help to provide more power.

(1) USB ports may have current protection in a form of "resettable" fuses. Y-cable will help to stay below disconnect level;

(2) USB ports may have "upside IC switches" with pre-set limit as well - the Y-cable will help, same as above;

(3) Each contact pair in USB connector has certain resistance, 15 milliOhms, 30 mOhms, depending on quality of contact finish and other factors. Having two contacts in parallel reduces the contact resistance and corresponding voltage droop decreases, so Y-cable will still help.

(A2) The cable can supply more power, true. However, the recipient of that power (portable device/phone) may not "take" more power, because it likely will not see a proper "charging signature", and the intelligent charger inside the phone will not take more power than a standard single USB port must supply, or 500mA in common case, or 900mA if the phone AND CABLE AND host PORT are USB3.

So, the answer to the question, can one GET more power from Y-cable, is "it depends".